# How do I append instead of overwrite here? (and how does this code open a file?)

Tags: c++, io, openfoam

I was going through an OpenFoam (v7) (C++) tutorial and came across this code for IO:

```
    // Create a custom directory and write an output file

    // Create the output path directory
    fileName outputDir = mesh.time().path()/"postProcessing";
    // Createe the directory
    mkDir(outputDir);
    // File pointer to direct the output to
        autoPtr<OFstream> outputFilePtr;
    // Open the file in the newly created directory
    outputFilePtr.reset(new OFstream(outputDir/"customOutputFile.dat");
    // Write stuff
    outputFilePtr() << "# This is a header" << endl;
    outputFilePtr() << "0 1 2 3 4 5" << endl;
```

Could somebody please help explain how this file is opened (I don't understand     `outputFilePtr.reset(new OFstream(outputDir/"customOutputFile.dat");`)
and how to append instead of overwrite? Adding std::ios::app doesn't seem to work here.

The constructor for openfoam-v7 is:

```
        OFstream
        (
            const fileName& pathname,
            streamFormat format=ASCII,
            versionNumber version=currentVersion,
            compressionType compression=UNCOMPRESSED,
            const bool append = false
        );
```

which can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-7/blob/master/src/OpenFOAM/db/IOstreams/Fstreams/OFstream.H)
and

```
141         outputFilePtr.reset( new OFstream(outputDir/"customOutputFile.dat",
142                                 ASCII,
143                                 currentVersion,
144                                 UNCOMPRESSED,
145                                  true) );
```

fails to error: ‘ASCII’ was not declared in this scope,
error: ‘currentVersion’ was not declared in this scope and
error: ‘UNCOMPRESSED’ was not declared in this scope.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you tag a C++ question with C you attract many C experts which then will look for excuses to downvote or close your question.

Comment: If `OFstream` is anything like `std::ofstream`. then it opens the file by using a non-default stream constructor, and there should be additional arguments to the constructor that specify the mode. Consult `OFstream` documentation. See also [std::ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) documentation.

Comment: Wow, the code organization of that project is terrible. Here's the [`OFstream.h`](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/blob/master/src/OpenFOAM/db/IOstreams/Fstreams/OFstream.H) declaring that type - which you presumably have a local copy of and can read. Look at the constructors. Hint: line 106.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OFstream](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/guides/latest/api/classFoam_1_1OFstream.html#details) constructor:

```
OFstream(
    const fileName& pathname,
    IOstreamOption  streamOpt = IOstreamOption(),
    const bool      append = false 
)
```

So:

```
outputFilePtr.reset( new OFstream(outputDir/"customOutputFile.dat", 
                                  IOstreamOption(),
                                  true) );
```

Edit: For the error with the old OpenFOAM version, it's most likely a namespace issue:

```
outputFilePtr.reset( new OFstream(outputDir/"customOutputFile.dat",
                                  Foam::IOstream::ASCII
                                  Foam::IOstream::currentVersion,
                                  Foam::IOstream::UNCOMPRESSED,
                                  true) );
```